# jQuery ajax not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to implement some ajax function in my `php` website. I basically know how to use jQuery, but for some reason, the returned value is always empty when I `alert()` it. This is the code I use:

**PHP:**

```
if(_POST('ajax'))
{
    $ajax_action = _POST('ajax');
    if($ajax_action == "gwonline")
    {
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

**JS / jQuery:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: './include/ajax.php',
    data: {ajax: 'gwonline'},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(output) {
        alert(output);
    }
});
```

I debugged it and it does call the file with an ajax request and returns the value, but not received apparently.. What am I doing wrong here? I sincerely don't know..

Comment: Wait what? Is `alert(output);` empty or not? You said _“the returned value is always empty”_ but then _“returns the value”_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The response should be pass by `echo` function, not `return`. So you must use `echo 'test';` instead of `return 'test';`

Comment: Thanks that's it! Anyway, do you by any chance know how to return an array or something of that sort and access multiple values from output? Like output.fname and output.lname?

Comment: You can make array, and use `json_encode` function for returning more than one simple string. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) is the useful link with good examples for learning this function.

Answer (score -2):

Don't forget using $ sign in front of every variable in php.

Comment: I did use $ sign. It has nothing to do with it.

Comment: May be I'm mistaken, but what is this? _POST('ajax')

Comment: I made a function called `_POST()` which gets a string and returns the `POST`ed value. It's my improvement to `$_POST[]`